# Trying to show a measure extends to a product sigma-algebra.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\mu,\nu$ be finite measures on $(E, \mathcal{E})$ and $(F, \mathcal{F} )$, respectively. $\mu(E), \nu(F)$ not necesarily equal to $1$. Let $\lambda = \mu \otimes \nu $ on $( E \times F , \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F} )$ by defined by

$$ \lambda( A \times B ) = \mu(A) \nu(B) $$

where $A \in \mathcal{E} $ and $B \in \mathcal{F}$.
Then $\lambda$ extends to a finite measure on $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}$

I know this result is true when $\mu , \nu $ are probability measures. How can I show it in this case? Is there a way to make $\mu, \nu $ into probability measures and then apply the theorem I already know ?

Comment: You didn't state a result. Are you asking if there exist such a measure $\lambda$?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question. yes, i am asking if $\lambda$ extends to finite measure on the product measure

Comment: The proof in the case of probability measures will carry over with no changes to the case of finite measures.

Comment: but $\mu $ and $\nu $ are not necesarilly equal to $1$. How can I make $\mu $ and $\nu $ equal to $1$ ?

Comment: I see. You can get the general finite case as a corollary of the probability case as answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ are finite measures on $\cal E$ and $\cal F$ respectively and define
$\bar \mu(A) = \dfrac{\mu(A)}{\mu(E)}$, $\bar \nu(B) = \dfrac{\nu(B)}{\mu(F)}$.  Then $\bar \mu$, $\bar \nu$ are probabilities so there exists a measure $\bar \lambda$ on $\cal E \otimes \cal F$ satisfying $$\bar \lambda (A \times B) = \bar \mu(A) \bar \nu (B)$$ whenever $A \in \cal E$, $B \in \cal F$. Now define
$$ \lambda(X) = \mu(E) \nu(F) \bar \lambda(X), \quad X \in \cal E \otimes \cal F.$$  Then $\lambda$ is a measure and $$\lambda (A \times B) = \mu(E) \nu(F) \bar \lambda(A \times B) = \mu(E) \nu(F) \bar \mu(A) \bar \nu (B) = \mu(A) \nu(B)$$
whenever $A \in \cal E$, $B \in \cal F$.